# controller action execute two times with Ajax.ActionLink and JQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have ajax.actionlink

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Click here",//link text
  "Insert", // action name
  "Projects",  // controller
  new { poz = item.itemID.ToString() }, // route values 
  new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetID = "PrjDiv" OnSuccess = "Initiate_Dialog" }, // ajax options
  new { @class = "openDialog", @id = item.idemID.ToString() } //htmlAttributes
  )
```

and jQuery UI dialog

```
function Initiate_Dialog() {
    var itemID= $(this).attr("id").replace("item_", "");
    var prjID= $("#m_project").val();

    var url = encodeURI("/Projects/Insert?poz=" + itemID+ "&proj=" + prjID);


    $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
        title: 'Insert',
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 'auto',
        width: 650,
        show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,

        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load(url);
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },

        buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
    return false;
}
```

When i click on generated link, my controller action is executed 2 times. Once with parameters sent from ajax.actionlink, and second time, with parameters sent from javascript.

I know that i have 2 calls and that's why is action executed twice. My question is, is there a way around this to execute only call from javascript, and not from actionlink?

Comment: IMO you can simply get rid of the `@Ajax.ActionLink` and use a regular html <a> for the link.

Comment: can't. page it's combination of several partial views with unobtrusive updates showing data from different tables in database.

Comment: Getting confused, isn't you wanting to make the request using unobtrusive ajax to be ceased? Also from what I see, the request from `@Ajax.ActionLink` isn't updating any of your html, since it doesn't has `InsertionMode` and `UpdateTargetId`. I am not sure if the first call has any meaning, but if not, you can simply make the link an `<a>` and bind `Initiate_Dialog()` to its onclick.

Comment: i accidentaly removed UpdateTargetID when i pasted code... sry